# Ajax links not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried to spice up my code with ajax. In fact i want to add ajax to patients/index      #patientenajax

```
<h1>Listing patients</h1>

 <div id="patientenajax"><%= render "patienten" %></div>
```

Next i in application.js i added:

```
 $(function() {
 $("#patientenajax th a").on("click", function(){
   $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
 });
});
```

And in an new created file index.js.erb:

```
$("#patientenajax").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'patienten') %>")
```

But somehow the ajax or better said the links in #patientenajax th a show no reaction:

```
<div class="pagination">
<ul>
<li class="prev">
<a rel="prev" href="/patients?page=5">← Previous</a>
</li> 
<li>
<a rel="start" href="/patients?page=1">1</a>
</li>..............
```

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Nothing! Thats the strange thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by default rails-3 uses jQuery 1.9.1 (or that's the least, can't remember!).  The `live` method was removed in version `1.9` http://api.jquery.com/live/.  You should be using `on` http://api.jquery.com/on/ instead:

```
//application.js
$(function() {
 $("#patientenajax th a, #patientenajax .pagination a").on("click", function(){
   $.getScript(this.href);
   return false;
 });
});
```

Comment: Ah youre right!! Now my console no more shows errors but somehow the links till show no reaction!

Comment: @EmSta, I've updated the answer.  Remove the `return false;` to have the links working.

Comment: @vinodadhikay now the page reloads! What ajax normally should avoid, right? If you compare railscast #240 you will see that he also uses return false! But thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I haven't really worked with `will_paginate` gem, but looking at the source of the railscast I see that the selectors involved are `#patientenajax th a` and `#patientenajax .pagination a`?  Have you tried them?

Comment: Yes! But i will try it today again!